# Follow/do/etc a plan?

Tags: collocations

When you want to say *do as you already planned* or *make a plan happen*, do you say *do the plan, follow the plan,* etc? I'm not sure what verb to use before plan to make that meaning. I think *Follow the plan* is a common collocation but it doesn't imply ***getting something done***; I feel it describes the process at any point, so it doesn't make the meaning I intend to make.

> I'm not sure I can [the verb] my plan.

What verb can I put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "plan" the verb would be "implement".  We **implement** a plan.

> I'm not sure we can **implement** the plan.
>
> I'm not sure the plan can **be implemented**.
>
> I'm not sure we can **put** the plan **into effect**.
>
> I'm not sure the plan can be **put into effect**.
>
> I'm not sure we can **carry out** the plan.
>
> I'm not sure the plan can be **carried out**.
>
> I'm not sure we can **follow through with** the plan.
>
> I'm not sure the plan can be **followed through with**.

Comment: Thanks, is there an easier option, too? Honest, I want to explain the meaning of _might_ for a possible plan to a kid.

Comment: What is "easier" is often in the eye of the beholder.  Put...into effect uses smaller words, but it's more difficult in that it is not a single word but a phrase.

Comment: Yea, I guessed so. BTW +1 :)

Comment: I like **carry out** myself.  Native speakers may avoid such verbs in writing (because they were taught to do so) but in speech, they are everywhere.